# Set href of anchor tag inside of LoggedInTemplate

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create Dynamic link to user Profile, but it wont work as i expect.

i tryed this:

```
    <li class='last' style="float:right"> <a id="loginLink2" runat="server" href="~/Profile/"+<asp:LoginName runat="server" />""
> ><asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />  </a></l>>                                             <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" OnLoggedOut="LoginStatus1_LoggedOut"
> LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />></li>
```

But its didnt work. How do i get around this problem? I could do it by ajax call to the server, but i want to avoid it if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to manually set it from the server.  You could do this on loading the page via:

```
((HtmlLink)LoginView1.FindControl("loginLink2")).href = "~/Profile/" +
          this.User.Identity.Name;
```

The one part I don't know is what the server-side control that represents an `<a runat="server">`... but everything else should work.